# Python program determining the letter based on row and col

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

My current code is under here with the pattern I want to be displayed

```
XOOOOOX
OXOOOXO
OOXOXOO
OOOXOOO
OOXOXOO
OXOOOXO
XOOOOOX
```

Code:

```
#starting from the 1st row and ending at the 8th row
for row in range (1, 8):
    
    #within each row, starting from the 1st col and ending in the 8th col
    for col in range(1, 8):
        #decide what to print at the current location
        if ((row - col)) == 0:
            print("X", end="")
        elif((row + 1)) == 0:
             print("X", end="")
        else:
            print("O", end="")

    #go onto the next row
    print()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your question?

Comment: Do you want to print only X or all the letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display x, the following code is sufficient:
You can differ the size of letter by N, try to avoid hard-coding some arbitrally numbers.

```
N = 8
    # starting from the 1st row and ending at the 8th row
for row in range(1, N):
    # within each row, starting from the 1st col and ending in the 8th col
    for col in range(1, N):
        # decide what to print at the current location
        if row == col or row == N-col:
            print("X", end="")
        else:
            print("O", end="")

    # go onto the next row
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it seems like I was adding unnecessary steps and this looks so much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Your logic does nothing to insert the second `X`, as you've seen.

```
for row in range (1, 8):
    ...
    elif((row + 1)) == 0:
```

Since row takes on values in the range 0-7, this isn't possible: it can be true only when `row = -1`.  Yes, Python allows you to index a list from the right, but a variable used as an index does not automatically take on a second value to satisfy those semantics.  You have to explicitly give it a single value.

You need to rewrite your condition to compare `row` to the end index, and you'll have to involve `col`, just as you did with the main diagonal.

Comment: while someone else flat out gave me the code just now, this really helped me to understand the actual error of what I was doing, I appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction, and also so quickly since I just posted this. Thank you again, and sorry if my post wasn't formatted correctly, this is my first time submitting something on here.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to list and make the change symmetrical based on the length of your string and the current i

```
LEN = 7#length of string
string = ""

#initialize string
for i in range(LEN):
    string += "O"
    
#change and print
for i in range(LEN):
    new_string = list(string)#from string to list
    new_string[i] = "X"#change the i
    new_string[LEN-i-1] = "X"#symmetrical change
    new_string = "".join(new_string)#list to string
    print(new_string)
```

You can change the LEN and the characters as you wish